# Why i cant use peripherial api in api computer craft?

Tags: lua, computercraft

Any attempt to call a peripheral in the API returns nil Do you know whether it is possible to use peripherals in the API or ways to use them?

I tried to write an api that will make it easier to work with monitors, but I can’t call their functions

Comment: "If no peripheral is connected, returns nil.", are you sure the side is correct and is a valid peripherial?

Comment: Yes, peripherial.isPresent returns "true"

Comment: What method are you trying to call? What would you expect it to return?

Comment: peripherial.call("top", clear)

Comment: I'm trying to call this function from the API but it returns null

Comment: I'm working with a monitor if that's the case

Comment: I assume you meant `peripherial.call("top", "clear")`? In any case, clear returns nil as intended, see https://computercraft.info/wiki/Term_(API)

Comment: the problem is that any attempt to call the peripheral from the API returns zero

Comment: Yes, that's what the doc said. Clear returns nil. What do you expect it to return?

Comment: I want it to just perform its function, not necessarily to return something

Comment: So the actual problem is that `peripherial.call("top", "clear")` does not clear the monitor? Text etc is still visible? (notice my fixed clear here, your example wont work)

Comment: yes, I tried to do this, the function does not work, and I understand that it cannot call the periphery

Comment: Then I'm clueless. Maybe share a screenshot of your setup after you called the function, as well as the code snippet you used.

Comment: okay i cant load scren shoots

Comment: i trying to
(OpenPeripherial addon)

in API
   glas = peripherial.wrap("top")
function func()
   glas.addBox(args)
end

in test
  load api
  api.func

what i reduce

"attempt to index ? ( a nil value)

Comment: trying to display the table number will do nothing